# Consistent and robust options to convert ICNS files to PNG in macOS?

Tags: terminal, graphics, icon, file-conversion, image-processing

I've been having a terrible time getting `sips` and/or ImageMagick (`convert`) to consistently convert `.icns` files to `.png`.

I frequently hit very unclear errors when using `sips` to make the conversion (eg, `sips -s format png "/path/to icns file/file.icns" --out "/path/to png file to generate/file.png"`) and when I end up with problems with that, I have usually been able to use ImageMagick (eg, `convert "/path/to icns file/file.icns" "/path/to png file to generate/file.png"`). I'm suspecting there are inconsistencies in the `.icns` files that I'm attempting to convert, but the `sips` error/output messages are sometimes nonsensical and unhelpful in this regard. When I hit these issues I can usually use ImageMagick, but not always.

Has anyone come up with a reliable method for converting `.icns` to `.png`?

Comment: What errors occur with `sips`?

Comment: Do you mind if it involves the clipboard ?

Comment: Is this a bulk operation? If not, you can open the icns file in Preview and drag it out to get a tiff or Save As... to a PNG